# Вывести все данные из таблицы 1, которых нет в таблице 2

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, таблицы

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста:
вот у меня есть 2 таблицы:

table1(id,name)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 4 | name3 |

---

table2(id,name)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | name2 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 4 | name4 |

как мне вывести все данные из таблицы 1, которых нет в таблице 2? (MySql)?

Comment: посмотрите какие join бывают

Comment: про join знаю. Не понимаю как составить запрос. Пробовал уже inner join table2 t2 on t1.id!=t2.id and t1.name!=t2.name. Но это все не правильно, поскольку у меня могут быть одинаковые id, но разные имена, и наоборот

Comment: Варианты: 1. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL 2. WHERE NOT EXISTS 3. WHERE NOT IN

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. использовал left join where is null